# How does Unix init configure stdin and stdout?

Tags: unix, kernel

I am trying to learn more about how Unix kernel works, and I am trying to dissect exactly what /bin/init does in Unix to config terminal /dev/tty0 as stdin and stdout.

Is it something as simple as

```
int fd = open("/dev/tty0", O_RDWR);
```

or is there more to it than that?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure `init` is attached to a terminal. I think that you are interested in process group management, but I can be wrong (I apologize in advance).

Shells usually are (attached), and yes there is much more things to do it correctly, the main thing to do is to bind in some way processes to terminal such that some events are correctly handled (signal handling, session termination, etc). To have a correct management of process related to the same terminal you need to consider : process groups and sessions. I can recommend you to read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group and `setpgrp`/`setsid` manuals.

Also, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58186/concept-of-controlling-terminal-in-unix